# Trying to train a variable GNN w/ GeometricFlux.jl

Tags: julia

I am trying to train a gated graph neural network to predict molecular properties with GeometricFlux.jl: https://github.com/FluxML/GeometricFlux.jl

The inputs are FeaturedGraph objects of various morphologies. After quite a bit of trial-and-error, I have reached a point where the exception message is opaque to me and I do not know how to proceed. Code:

```
using Flux, GeometricFlux, MetaGraphs

# convert a MetaGraph to FeaturedGraph
mg = MetaGraph()
adj_mat = adjacency_matrix(mg)
g = FeaturedGraph(adj_mat; nf=ones(2, nv(mg)))

# train the model
model = Chain(GatedGraphConv(2, 1, aggr=:mean), softmax)
loss(x, y) = Flux.mse(model(x), y)
@Flux.epochs 1 Flux.train!(
    loss, 
    Flux.params(model), 
    [(g, 1.0)], 
    ADAM()
)
```

The error message is: `LoadError: MethodError: _pullback(::Zygote.Context, ::typeof(hcat)) is ambiguous.`

Can anyone suggest what is wrong?